# How to parse a optional JSON object using JSONJoy?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy-Swift
For example :

```
JSON1 = {
"message": "Sorry! Password does not match.",
"code": "4"
}

JOSN2 = {
"data": {
"id": 21
},
"message": "Signup Successful.",
"code": "1"
},
```

Here json key “data” is optional. Then how I can handle both response using the same model object??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONJoy natively sets not found elements to nil, you just have to declare them optional and then check for nil before using them.

From the docs

> This also has automatic optional validation like most Swift JSON libraries.
>
> //some randomly incorrect key. This will work fine and the property
>   will just be nil.
>
> firstName = decoder[5]["wrongKey"]["MoreWrong"].string
>
> //firstName is nil, but no crashing!

Here is my example that my be illustrative. I have a complex object set where my top level object (UserPrefs) has arrays of secondary objects (SmartNetworkNotification and SmartNotificationTime).

Note that notifications and times are both declared as optional. What I do is check for nil after attempting to parse the secondary object arrays. Without the nil check the attempt to iterate on the parsed list fails since its nil. With the nil check it just moves past it if its empty.

This works for me but isn't deeply tested yet. YMMV! Curious how others are handling it.

```
struct UserPrefs: JSONJoy {
    var notifications: [SmartNetworkNotification]?
    var times: [SmartNotificationTime]?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) throws {
        // Extract notifications
        let notificationsJson = try decoder["notifications"].array
        if(notificationsJson != nil){
            var collectNotifications = [SmartNetworkNotification]()
            for notificationDecoder in notificationsJson! {
                do {
                    try collectNotifications.append(SmartNetworkNotification(notificationDecoder))
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error.. on notifications decoder")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            notifications = collectNotifications
        }

        // Extract time of day settings

        let timesJson = try decoder["times"].array
        if(timesJson != nil){
            var collectTimes = [SmartNotificationTime]()
            for timesDecoder in timesJson! {
                do {
                    try collectTimes.append(SmartNotificationTime(timesDecoder))
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error.. on timesJson decoder")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            times = collectTimes
        }
    }
```